# Why is GNU screen / byobu leaving garbage text in the shell during a reverse search?

Tags: shell, ssh, gnu-screen, opensolaris, byobu

I recently starting using GNU screen via Byobu but I think the problem is related to screen.

I first SSH into a server and then do a reverse search to run a commonly run command (dump a the database). I've redacted some of the text, but because  usually outputs `(reverse-i-search)`':` before the search, it pushed the line across the width of the terminal.

[image: screenshot1]

If I am happy with the search and accept the command, the rightmost text stays put. See below:

[image: screenshot2]

So, why is this "garbage text" staying in the window? It only happens in screen and only seems to happen for certain hosts that use my custom .bashrc formatting and don't have their own.

Comment: This is likely to be a shell misconfiguration, probably the lack of prompt protection [suggested by mikel](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6580/why-is-gnu-screen-byobu-leaving-garbage-text-in-the-shell-during-a-reverse-sear/6581#6581). What shell are you using (probably bash, but please confirm)?

Comment: I am using bash. I will look at my PS1 and if I can't figure it out, post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing `\[` and `\]` in your `PS1`.  It needs to go around every non-printing escape sequence, e.g. the escape sequences used to color things blue and yellow.

See the bash man page for details.  It's in the section titled "Prompting".

It's also documented in the info docs under [Controlling the Prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt).

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at the color escape sequences. Weird that it doesn't happen in any other terminal...